# Node.js Cluster load balancing in endpoint level

Tags: node.js, express, cluster-computing, load-balancing, node-cluster

I use **cluster** and have 2 nodes that were running. each node has one API that was doing a task for around 5-6 seconds.

For example

in cluster.js

```
const cluster = require("cluster");

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }
} else {
  require("./server");
}
```

and here in server.js

```
  const express = require("express");
  const app = express();
  const port = 8080;

  app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
   await sleep(5000);
   res.send('handled by process: ' + process.pid);
  });

  async function sleep (ms){
    if (ms <= 0) return;
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    });
  };

  app.listen(port, () => console.log(`port: ${port}`));
```

if I request to the API. The first node received the request and process around 5-6 seconds. Before it finishes the process and response, I send the second request to the API. But the request is sent to the first node, not the second node. How to implement a node cluster to do this?

Comment: How are you using the cluster? Can you post the related code?

Comment: Ok, I just edited the code.

Comment: That's normal. The first process is not overloaded, so it can still handle the request effortlessly. According to the docs "". https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_how_it_works

Comment: Just try overloading  it and you will see that the two nodes will get to work.

Comment: Thanks, But do you know any node.js feature or library that can do this without overloading?